# Вывод содержимого папки с трансляцией

Tags: php

Я написал на php, читая книги, скрипт, 
в нем есть две задачи, я их не могу решить.
 **Первое**, то, что функция *transliterate* (делает английские буквы русскими) переводит в русский и расширение файлов, что **не нужно**. 
**Второе**, в строке `<a href='.$file.'>'.transliterate($file).'</a>';` нужно изменить путь к файлу 
(то-есть перед .$file.  должна быль еще папка, вот так  `<a href='папку нужно вставить сдесь.$file.'>'.transliterate($file).'</a>';`
но как бы я не старался это вызывает ошибку.
 Вот сам скрипт:

```
$dir = opendir("akkordy/");
while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
    if (($file != ".") && ($file != "..") && ($file != "index.php")) {
        echo '<img src="/gitara/themes/present/images/PostCategoryIcon.png" WIDTH="50" HEIGHT="50" alt=""><a href='папку нужно вставить сдесь.$file.'>'.transliterate($file).'</a>';
    }
}
closedir($dir);

// Транслитерация строк. 
function transliterate($st)
{
    $st = strtr($st, array(
        "ё" => 'yo',
        "х" => 'h',
        "ц" => 'ts',
        "ч" => 'ch',
        "ш" => 'sh',
        "щ" => 'shch',
        "ю" => 'yu',
        "я" => 'ya',
        "Ё" => 'Yo',
        "Х" => 'H',
        "Ц" => 'Ts',
        "Ч" => 'Ch',
        "Ш" => 'Sh',
        "Щ" => 'Shch',
        "Ю" => 'Yu',
        "Я" => 'Ya'
    ));
    $st = strtr($st, "abvgdejziyklmnoprstufieABVGDEJZIYKMNOPRSTUFIE", "абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфЫэАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФЫЭ");
    return $st;
}
```

ответ на вопрос
Вот что получилось в итоге

```
// Транслитерация строк. 
function transliterate($st) {
$st = strtr($st, array(
"ё"=>'yo',    "х"=>'h',  "ц"=>'ts',  "ч"=>'ch', "ш"=>'sh',   
"щ"=>'shch',  "ю"=>'yu', "я"=>'ya', 
"Ё"=>'Yo',    "Х"=>'H',  "Ц"=>'Ts',  "Ч"=>'Ch', "Ш"=>'Sh', 
"Щ"=>'Shch',  "Ю"=>'Yu', "Я"=>'Ya'
));
$st = strtr($st,
"abvgdejziyklmnoprstufieABVGDEJZIYKMNOPRSTUFIE",
"абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфЫэАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФЫЭ"
);
return $st;
}
$dir = opendir ("."); //путь к файлам
while ( $file = readdir ($dir)) 
{ 
if (( $file != ".") && ($file != "..") && ( $file != "index.php")) 
{
$z = transliterate($file);
echo '<img src="адрес картинки" WIDTH="50" HEIGHT="50" alt=""><a href="папка к файлу $dir почему то не ведет к файлу /'.$file.'">'.basename("$z", "зип").PHP_EOL.zip.'</a>';
} 
} 
closedir ($dir);
```

Но появилась еще проблема, если файлы в под-папках, тогда открывается страница браузера с файлами и не романтическим названием Index of???

Answer (score 2):

Первый вариант ответа

```
 $dir = opendir("akkordy/");
    while ($file = readdir($dir)) 
        if (($file != ".") && ($file != "..") && ($file != "index.php")) 
            echo '<img src="/gitara/themes/present/images/PostCategoryIcon.png" WIDTH="50" HEIGHT="50" alt=""><a href="akkordy/' . $file . '">' . transliterate($file) . '</a>';

    closedir($dir);

    // Транслитерация строк. 
    function transliterate($st)
    {
        $st = strtr($st, array(
            "ё" => 'yo',
            "х" => 'h',
            "ц" => 'ts',
            "ч" => 'ch',
            "ш" => 'sh',
            "щ" => 'shch',
            "ю" => 'yu',
            "я" => 'ya',
            "Ё" => 'Yo',
            "Х" => 'H',
            "Ц" => 'Ts',
            "Ч" => 'Ch',
            "Ш" => 'Sh',
            "Щ" => 'Shch',
            "Ю" => 'Yu',
            "Я" => 'Ya'
        ));
        $st = strtr($st, "abvgdejziyklmnoprstufieABVGDEJZIYKMNOPRSTUFIE", "абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфЫэАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФЫЭ");
        return $st;
    }
```

Второй вариант ответа.

```
  $dir = opendir("akkordy/");
 $trans = array("а"=>"a","б"=>"b","в"=>"v","г"=>"g","д"=>"d","е"=>"e", 
"ё"=>"yo","ж"=>"j","з"=>"z","и"=>"i","й"=>"i","к"=>"k","л"=>"l", "м"=>"m", 
"н"=>"n","о"=>"o","п"=>"p","р"=>"r","с"=>"s","т"=>"t", 
"у"=>"y","ф"=>"f","х"=>"h","ц"=>"c","ч"=>"ch", "ш"=>"sh","щ"=>"sh", 
"ы"=>"i","э"=>"e","ю"=>"u","я"=>"ya", 
"А"=>"A","Б"=>"B","В"=>"V","Г"=>"G","Д"=>"D","Е"=>"E", "Ё"=>"Yo", 
"Ж"=>"J","З"=>"Z","И"=>"I","Й"=>"I","К"=>"K", "Л"=>"L","М"=>"M", 
"Н"=>"N","О"=>"O","П"=>"P", "Р"=>"R","С"=>"S","Т"=>"T","У"=>"Y", 
"Ф"=>"F", "Х"=>"H","Ц"=>"C","Ч"=>"Ch","Ш"=>"Sh","Щ"=>"Sh", 
"Ы"=>"I","Э"=>"E","Ю"=>"U","Я"=>"Ya", 
"ь"=>"","Ь"=>"","ъ"=>"","Ъ"=>"");

while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
    if (($file != ".") && ($file != "..") && ($file != "index.php")) {
      //  echo '<img src="/gitara/themes/present/images/PostCategoryIcon.png" WIDTH="50" HEIGHT="50" alt=""><a href="akkordy/'.$file.'">'.transliterate($file).'</a>';
      echo strtr($file, $trans);      
    }
}
closedir($dir);
```

Так даже сделать можно.

ps кодировку правильную только сделай на файле

Comment: Вторая проблема решена (синтаксис).
Спасибо Shrek.

Comment: Ну если что-то помогло можно +1 или принять ответ.

Comment: Нет это будет уже не на русский, а на английский переводить. У меня он по крайней мере так делает. Куда сложнее решить первый вопрос.

Comment: Значит наоборот сделай массив, из инглиша в русский, там местами поменять то всего делов :)

Comment: Можно как то перед выводом убрать расширения?

Comment: Можно. explode(".",$file);